# How does Dota 2's "Watch highlights" Replay pick the highlights?

Tags: dota-2

Sometimes you can select something like "Watch highlights" of a Dota 2 replay.

One day I made a Rampage (killed five people at once) with Techies' Remote Mines, and I thought about watching the replay using the watch highlights function. It showed some boring tower fights—I mean one guy pushing a non defended tower, for example. My Rampage (Pentakill for our LoL players) was not part of it.

How are the highlights selected by Dota 2? Does anybody know this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure (but may be completely wrong) that DoTA 2 picks the "highlights" of the game by simply showing: Kills; fights, Tower destruction, Roshan killing, courier killing etc. (Basically everything eventful apart from people running around jungle or farming) and skipping from one eventful length of footage (time in the match that XYZ happened) to another. Of course, in chronological order too.

Comment: so why is a rampage not part of it :)? I thought some should be def. part of it while something else CAN be part

Answer (score 5):

Given that Techies is a new hero and his kills are pretty much all remotely done : it didn't show on the highlights. Highlights have an algorithm that shows kills when there are more than 2 heroes involved like 2vs1 (gank) or more (team fight). Highlights also shows tower kills, Roshan kills etc. Its not that perfect but I'm 99% sure it's because no one in your team was involved in the rampage.

Comment: I like that answer, indeed I think we were all dead and lost a teamfight right before.

Comment: It skips some things.

Comment: Otherwise it would be called replay, right? -.

Comment: Also I think the fight must be longer than a few seconds. And since the remote detonation was you know... instakill... Note: The fb makes exception to this rules, I noticed that no matter how boring/lame/instant it is, it is always shown.

Comment: now in my newer replays it shows my ownage using techies. It seems that they changed something